# How would I map over one property of all CoreData entries?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a CoreData `entity` named `Ticket` which represents the work done on a job. Every job has hours and I would like to get all of the hours done for `companyX`. So for example:

If I have

```
Verizon: 8
Netflix: 8
AMEX: 8
Verizon: 8
```

How would I map over all the `Verizon` jobs and get 16 hours

[image]

I can't think of how I would do this although I think I would have to edit the `Ticket + CoreDataProperties` file.

Would I perform the mapping here

`@FetchRequest(entity: Ticket.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])`

or somewhere else?

Comment: Try computed/derived attributes [PassingCuriosity](https://passingcuriosity.com/2008/computed-attributes-in-core-data-how/) [Avanderlee](https://www.avanderlee.com/core-data/derived-attributes-optimise-fetch-performance/)

Comment: Here is [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/) it is at about minute 19

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks a lot! I can tell this is sort of arcane knowledge.

Comment: Just a bit obscure but very helpful. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770742/core-data-derivation-expression-key-path-uses-an-operator-as-an-intermediate-com) that might help with an `@sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty obscure but a Computed/Derived attribute does this for you.

A description of an attribute of a Core Data entity that derives its value from one or more other properties.

It is hard to describe but here are some resources

[PassingCuriosity](https://passingcuriosity.com/2008/computed-attributes-in-core-data-how/)

[Avanderlee](https://www.avanderlee.com/core-data/derived-attributes-optimise-fetch-performance/)

Here is [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/) it is at about minute 19

And an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770742/core-data-derivation-expression-key-path-uses-an-operator-as-an-intermediate-com) that deals with an error with `@sum`

[NSDerivedAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription)

[Function names](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-217733)

[image: Data Model Inspector]

Comment: Although I’m using manually created CoreData class but the avanderlee post you shared gives a solution for that too, and still watching WWDC